# Checking type of data within an array

Tags: iphone, nsarray

I have an array which contains text data and image data.If data is text i need to display it in a label otherwise in an imageview.But how to detect whether its a text or image?

Comment: How is imageData stored in the array?

Comment: Have u stored both image and text in one array ?

Answer (score 2):

if( [[ array objectAtIndex: yourIndex] isKindOfClass: [ Name_of_the_class_your_want_to_check_for class ]] )

Comment: the questioner has mention to display it in a label so i assume its a text

Comment: +1 well don't expect him to accept your answer anyways ... (And not because it is not correct) :)

Comment: then what is for image class and video class

Comment: image are saved directly as UIImage object but you can save it also as NSData but normally for video only the paths are saved in the array